# Getting Age of Visitor on Website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, api, analytics

I need to write some code that gets the gender and age of a visitor on my website without asking for permission to store them, just like Google Analytics.

I have managed figure out a way of getting the users gender using by using the Facebook Graph API (gender does not require user permission). So now I am stuck on a way I could get the visitors age as I cannot use Facebook Graph API for this as it requires permission from the user to get.

Any ideas? Thanks for reading.

Comment: The Facebook API DOES in fact require user permission. Google Analytics gets data from various partners. The info does not just appear from nowhere.

Comment: Ask them a series of pop-music questions and estimate their age based on Bayesian learning algorithms.

Comment: You could ask. It's not like the age provided by Facebook is likely to be any more accurate.

Comment: I maintain my approach could be pretty darn accurate given a large enough training set.

Comment: did you want to know my blood type to ?

Comment: @relentless Once you have the ID of a user, you do not need any permissions. Check out this link. http://graph.facebook.com/4?fields=id,name,picture,gender

Comment: Would you explain why you want to ignore user permission settings? They are probably there for a reason. Would it not be better to just obtain permission?

Answer (score 9):

Here is a function that is just as accurate as Facebook but requires no user permissions.

```
function get_age() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 13) + 13);
}
```

If you want more accuracy, you can use multiple random numbers to skew the data into a more realistic distribution. See the jsfiddle I put together: http://jsfiddle.net/D7sj6/

Comment: Seems it could be made more accurate with some sort of statistical bell curve.